# Errors generated by Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I want to know why nodejs drop Error from 'Manual & Documentation'.
I was abble to find 'Node.js v0.11.14-pre Manual & Documentation' (http://neversaw.us/nodejs-api/errors.html).

I search on google a list of full error (like EADDRINUSE) but didn't find one.
Anyone have a full list of errors?

Adrian

Comment: that error in human readable format is 'Error: Address In Use.'. that typically means the port you are using is already being used.

Comment: I know what that error mean, it's listed on http://neversaw.us/nodejs-api/errors.html I want to know why node.js drop it

Answer (score 1):

Iojs nodejs fork has documention of both nodejs + iojs error https://iojs.org/api/errors.html

Comment: That's the question should be asked to Node JS TC.. :)